# Gamemaker export code for Gource

Tags: export, game-maker, gource

Is there a way to use Gamemaker with Gource?
Or is there something like a tool or library to export / convert .gmk files to .txt files each of them with one class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While pre-Studio projects are stored as single files, you can use [Gmk-Splitter](https://github.com/Medo42/Gmk-Splitter) to split the `.gmk` file into a number of XML files (not too unlike the format used by GameMaker: Studio) or recompose the file from a set.

While not ideal, this permits to use source control with older versions of GameMaker. See the author's "Gang-Garrison-2" repository for an example of that in action.

Answer (score 1):

With `.gmk` it's impossible. But if you will use GMS then you can try do it, because GMS uses `.xml` (i.e. text) files. I checked it with git and mercurial and it works fine.